# Bean creation error after upgrading Spring Batch project

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am in the midst of upgrading our team's Spring Batch project when i ran into the following error:

```
2966    main    WARN    org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker  PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:437  Bean 'jobRegistry' of type [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). Is this bean getting eagerly injected into a currently created BeanPostProcessor [jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor]? Check the corresponding BeanPostProcessor declaration and its dependencies.
3029    main    INFO    com.companyName.teamName.service.config.EncryptionConfiguration EncryptionConfiguration.java:22 No files to encrypt
3186    main    INFO    org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher SimpleJobLauncher.java:232  No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
3200    main    WARN    org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext  AbstractApplicationContext.java:624 Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobExplorer' defined in class path resource [context.xml]: TransactionManager must not be null.

3203    main    ERROR   org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner  CommandLineJobRunner.java:372   Job Terminated in error: Error creating bean with name 'jobExplorer' defined in class path resource [context.xml]: TransactionManager must not be null.

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobExplorer' defined in class path resource [context.xml]: TransactionManager must not be null.
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1775)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:946)
     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616)
     at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
     at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
     at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:295)
     at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:558)
     at com.companyName.teamName.batch.app.App.main(App.java:49)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: TransactionManager must not be null.
     at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:172)
     at org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.AbstractJobExplorerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractJobExplorerFactoryBean.java:119)
     at org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JobExplorerFactoryBean.java:204)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1822)
     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1771)
     ... 14 more
```

This error was thrown when trying to run the application.

Note that I have only changed the packages' versions in `build.gradle` & not made any functional changes. Hence I was not expecting any error to be thrown.

This is the older build.gradle, before the upgrade:

```
dependencies {
    // The production code uses the SLF4J logging API at compile time
    
    compile(group: 'BatchProject', name: 'BatchServiceTier', version: "1.0-SNAPSHOT")
    
    compile("org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.22")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.22")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-aop:5.3.22")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-expression:5.3.22")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.22")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-context-support:4.3.2.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-tx:5.3.22")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-oxm:5.3.22")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-aspects:5.3.22")
    compile("org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.4")
    compile('org.mybatis:mybatis:3.5.0')
    compile('org.mybatis:mybatis-spring:2.0.0')
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.4")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.3.22")
    compile("org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:4.0.2.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-infrastructure:4.0.2.RELEASE")
    compile("org.jasypt:jasypt:1.9.2")
    compile("org.jasypt:jasypt-spring31:1.9.2")
    compile("com.google.guava:guava:23.5-jre")
    compile("javax.mail:mail:1.4")
    compile("jcifs:jcifs:1.3.17")
    compile("commons-io:commons-io:2.6")    
    compile("commons-net:commons-net:3.6")
    compile("com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.54")
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.0'
    compile('commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6')

    //log4j
    compile ("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.1")
    compile ("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.17.1")
    compile ("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12")
    compile ("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.17.1")
    
    // DB2 Driver
    compile('com.ibm.db2:db2jcc_license_cisuz:1.0')
    compile('com.ibm.db2:db2java:1.0')
    compile('com.ibm.db2:jcc:11.5.0.0')
    
    testCompile ('org.jmockit:jmockit:1.8')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

This is the newer build.gradle, after the upgrade:

```
dependencies {
    // The production code uses the SLF4J logging API at compile time
    
    implementation(group: 'BatchProject', name: 'BatchServiceTier', version: "1.0-SNAPSHOT")
    
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-web:6.1.1")
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-core:6.1.1")
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-beans:6.1.1")
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-aop:6.1.1")
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-expression:6.1.1")
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-context:6.1.1")
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-context-support:6.1.1")
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-tx:6.1.1")
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-oxm:6.1.1")
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-aspects:6.1.1")
    implementation("org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.4")
    implementation('org.mybatis:mybatis:3.5.14')
    implementation('org.mybatis:mybatis-spring:3.0.3')
    implementation("mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.4")
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-jdbc:6.1.1")
    implementation("org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:5.1.0")
    implementation("org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-infrastructure:5.1.0")
    implementation("org.jasypt:jasypt:1.9.2")
    implementation("org.jasypt:jasypt-spring31:1.9.2")
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:32.1.3-jre")
    implementation("jakarta.mail:jakarta.mail-api:2.1.2")
    implementation("org.samba.jcifs:jcifs:1.3.3")
    implementation("commons-io:commons-io:2.15.0")  
    implementation("commons-net:commons-net:3.10.0")
    implementation("com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.55")
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.16.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.16.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.16.0'
    implementation('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.13.0')
    implementation('org.apache.velocity:velocity-engine-core:2.3')

    //log4j
    implementation ("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.21.1")
    implementation ("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.21.1")
    implementation ("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.9")
    implementation ("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.21.1")
    
    // DB2 Driver
    implementation('com.ibm.db2:db2jcc_license_cisuz:1.0')
    implementation('com.ibm.db2:db2java:1.0')
    implementation('com.ibm.db2:jcc:11.5.0.0')
    
    testImplementation 'org.jmockit:jmockit:1.8'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

This is the contents of `context.xml`, where the error is referring to:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd">

    <import resource="batchMyBatisSpringApplicationContext.xml" />
    <import resource="batchSpringApplicationContext.xml" />
    <import resource="myBatisSpringApplicationContext.xml" />
    <import resource="springApplicationContext.xml" />
    <!-- stored job-meta in database -->
    
    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${MYSQL_DB_DRIVER}" />
        <property name="url" value="${MYSQL_DB_URL}" />
        <property name="username" value="#{encryptedProperties.getProperty('MYSQL_DB_USER')}" />
        <property name="password" value="#{encryptedProperties.getProperty('MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD')}" />
    </bean>
  
    <bean id="jobRepository"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="databaseType" value="mysql" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="jobLauncher"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobExplorer"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />
    <bean id="jobRegistry"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry" />
    <bean id="jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor">
        <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="jobOperator"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator">
        <property name="jobExplorer">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
        <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry" />
        <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean class="com.companyName.commons.security.teamName.EncryptedProperties" id="propertyConfigurer">
        <constructor-arg value="classpath:batchconfig.properties"/>
    </bean>
    
</beans>
```

Before the upgrade, I was able to build the project with `gradlew build` & run it successfully. But now, the application cannot run & fails.

I see that there isn't a bean named `transactionManager` defined in the file `context.xml`. Will I need to define a bean named as such? Because there wasn't such a bean previously & the batch application was able to build & run.

I am aware there are changes when upgrading from Spring Batch 4.0 to 5.0, as listed by the Spring team here: [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide).

I am very new to this, appreciate the guidance from other folks here, thanks in advance.

### Update #1

I have added the following in `context.xml` but the same error is still being thrown

```
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
```

### Update #2

I have added the following lines in `context.xml`, to follow the example in Spring's "Configuring a JobRepository" guide here: [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/job/configuring-repository.html)

```xml
    <job-repository id="jobRepository"
        data-source="dataSource"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager"
        isolation-level-for-create="SERIALIZABLE"
        table-prefix="BATCH_"
        max-varchar-length="1000"/>
```

but was thrown the following error:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/
 beans":job-repository}'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import, "http://
 www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, 
 WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"], "http://www.springframework.org/schema/
 beans":beans}' is expected.
```

Comment: Please ad the complete stacktrace

Comment: hi @Jens, complete stacktrace has been added